# how to use filter on git tag with filter in the last or middle?

Tags: git

We usually filter on all tagging with description using `"git tag -n99 v*"`

but let say i have

```
v01.01.01
v01.01.02-Stable
v01.01.03
v01.01.04
v01.01.05-Stable
```

and currently i need to show all -Stable data with description, so how to do this?

i found nothing example if filtering is applied in the middle and in the last char, almost every example using prefix in filtering v123*

i need like "git tag -n99 -l *-Stable"

Comment: Did you try `git tag -n99 -l *-Stable`? It should work.

Answer (score 0):

I confirm that, in a local clone of the [`git/git`](https://github.com/git/git) repository for example, a suffix tag name filter does work:

```
 git tag -n99 -l *-rc1
```

That lists only `-rc1` tags

But if not, a simple `git tag -l|grep "\-rc1"` would work too.

Comment: i think n99 combine with grep is useless, since grep only capture 1 line and n99 will show more than 1 line. Would you please to correct me?

Comment: @kreamik I agree. I have edited the grep command accordingly.